# Can I comment a user with my email to get in touch?

Tags: discussion, email

Working on an open source project, I got stuck with a problem and a Stack Overflow user solved it beautifully. The way they solved it made me believe they could be interested in the project I am carrying on, and I would like to ask them to join.

I wonder: can I leave my email address in a comment to their answer asking them to get in touch if they feel inclined to hear about my project? Or is it against the policy? If it is, what else could I do to inform them about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, check the user's profile page and look for any contact information. Many users leave such info, e.g. twitter account, personal blog, etc.

If there is no information allowing you to contact that user in private then yes, you can post your email in a comment, there's no rule against it. Just keep in mind anyone else can see your email out in the public, including spam harvesters.

So in case you do post your email, make sure to delete it after a while, or if the user you try to contact responded.